# R: Get a matrix row without using 2d index syntax

Tags: r, matrix, indexing

I've got a matrix that looks as follows:

```
> train.y.class[1:2,]
     Class_1 Class_2 Class_3 Class_4 Class_5 Class_6 Class_7 Class_8 Class_9
[1,]       1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
[2,]       0       0       0       0       1       0       0       0       0
```

It then gets passed into the R function `tune`, which will perform a grid search on possible model parameters. In order to do this it regularly slices this data and passes it to the model. These slices are where it starts to break down; it does something like

```
do.call(model, x, y[1:n], ...)
```

... while `y[1:n]` returns a vector of n elements, instead of the wanted n x 9 matrix. That is, I need something that looks like the matrix above but instead I get something like this:

```
> train.y.class[1:2]
[1] 1 0
```

Since I can't access this library code my question is whether it is possible to reformat my matrix into a structure that allows slices of the form `y.new[1:n]` that result in the same as `y.old[1:n,]`, i.e. an n x 9 matrix. A clever hack, if you like.

If the answer is no, could you propose an alternative solution? I have experimented with a combination of alternative data representations (not a matrix) and a wrapper for the model, but I haven't quite got the hang of reformatting parameters and then calling the wrapped function.

Answer (score 0):

`y[1:n, ]` will return an n x 9 matrix.

When you subset a matrix with a one-dimensional argument, you simply get the elements of the matrix in column-major order:

```
> (mat <- matrix(letters[1:20], ncol = 5)) # example matrix
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] "a"  "e"  "i"  "m"  "q" 
[2,] "b"  "f"  "j"  "n"  "r" 
[3,] "c"  "g"  "k"  "o"  "s" 
[4,] "d"  "h"  "l"  "p"  "t" 

> mat[1:6] # returns vector of length six
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f"

> mat[2:3, ] # returns 2 x 6 matrix
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] "b"  "f"  "j"  "n"  "r" 
[2,] "c"  "g"  "k"  "o"  "s"
```

Comment: So do you know a conversion to a data structure that _would_ return a whole row with a single index? I know a list would work but I can't seem to figure out how to convert it.

Comment: To convert a the rows of a matrix into a list, try `split(<yourMatrix>, row(<yourMatrix>))`